Support of conditional expectation depends on conditional probability
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, $D_1,\ldots, D_n\in\mathcal{F}$ a disjoint decomposition of $\Omega$. Moreover let $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra, $\mathfrak{D}=\sigma(D_1,\ldots, D_n)$ and $f$ be a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable function, which is either integrable with repect to $P$ or non-negative. I would like to show that
$$\mathbb{1}_{\{P(D_i|\mathcal{G})=0\}}E[1_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]=0\quad P\text{-a.s.}$$
My attempt: For any $G\in\mathcal{G}$, it holds
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[\mathbb{1}_{G}\mathbb{1}_{D_i}E[\mathbb{1}_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]]
&=E[\mathbb{1}_{G}E[\mathbb{1}_{D_i}E[\mathbb{1}_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{G}]]\\
&=E[\mathbb{1}_{G}E[\mathbb{1}_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]E[\mathbb{1}_{D_i}|\mathcal{G}]]\\
&=E[\mathbb{1}_{G}E[\mathbb{1}_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]P(D_i|\mathcal{G})]\\
\end{aligned}
$$
This implies
$$\mathbb{1}_{D_i}E[\mathbb{1}_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]=E[\mathbb{1}_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]P(D_i|\mathcal{G})\quad P\text{-a.s.}$$
and
$$\mathbb{1}_{\{P(D_i|\mathcal{G})=0\}}\mathbb{1}_{D_i}E[1_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]=0\quad P\text{-a.s.}$$
This however implies
$$\mathbb{1}_{\{P(D_i|\mathcal{G})=0\}}E[1_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]=\mathbb{1}_{\{P(D_i|\mathcal{G})=0\}}\mathbb{1}_{(D_i)^c}E[1_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]\quad P\text{-a.s.}$$
How could I go on?

Notice, that $\{P(D_i \mid \mathcal{G})=0\}\cap D_i$ is a null set, since
$$P(\{P(D_i \mid \mathcal{G})=0\}\cap D_i)=E[1_{\{P(D_i \mid \mathcal{G})=0\}}1_ {D_i}]=E[1_{\{P(D_i \mid \mathcal{G})=0\}}P(D_i \mid \mathcal{G})]=0$$
Then, since $\{{P(D_i|\mathcal{G})=0\}}\in\mathcal{G}$, you find
$$E[1_G\mathbb{1}_{\{P(D_i|\mathcal{G})=0\}}E[1_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]]=E[1_G1_{\{P(D_i|\mathcal{G})=0\}}1_{D_i}f]=E[1_G1_{\{P(D_i|\mathcal{G})=0\}\cap D_i}f]=0$$
for any $G\in\mathcal{G}$, i.e.
$$\mathbb{1}_{\{P(D_i|\mathcal{G})=0\}}E[1_{D_i}f|\mathcal{G}]=0\quad P\text{-a.s.}$$

When $ P(D_i \mid G) = 0 $, the conditional expectation $ E[1_{D_i} f \mid G] $vanishes almost surely.
This is because the conditional probability of $D_i$ given G is zero, implying that $f$ is essentially zero on $D_i$ when conditioned on $G$.
Specifically, we have
$$
1\{ P(D_i \mid G) = 0 \} E[1_{D_i} f \mid G] = 1\{ P(D_i \mid G) = 0 \} 1_{D_i} E[f \mid G].
$$
Since $P(D_i \mid G) = 0$, we know that $E[f \mid G] = 0$ almost surely on the set $D_i$
Then
$$
1\{ P(D_i \mid G) = 0 \} E[f \mid G] = 0 \quad \text{P-a.s.}.
$$
Therefore, we conclude
$$
1\{ P(D_i \mid G) = 0 \} E[1_{D_i} f \mid G] = 0 \quad \text{P-a.s.}.
$$
This completes the proof.
Thank you!

Thank you for your reply. I didn't understand your proof though. How do you conclude $1{ P(D_i \mid G) = 0 } E[1_{D_i} f \mid G] = 1{ P(D_i \mid G) = 0 } 1_{D_i} E[f \mid G]$?
